# WSO2 API Manager redirect according to client

Tags: web-services, api, wso2, mediator

Is it possible to have the API Manager redirect an incoming client API call to a back-end URL customized according to the client data?

In our back-end we're activating different instance URLs for each client, e.g.:

- client1.api.domain.internal
- client2.api.domain.internal
- ...

Clients connect to the API Manager to a unique shared address, e.g. api.domain.ext, and then clients shall be routed to the internal API accordingly (the parameter is bound to the client profile).

Is this achievable via configuration or is it necessary to develop a custom component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use API manager.
Publish one API-A to the clients to subscribe publicly via publisher. Define another internal API-B (dont publish it) where do routing logic based on the clients' requests. 
Point the API_B as the production URL to the API_A. So, requests will be routed to your internal API-B, where you can define your mediation logic.

But for defining mediation logic, what you have to do is, open the API configuration in a TEXT editor and need to edit or via source view of the management console. You can follow ESB guide for various mediators to pick a right one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, in this case I should implement the routing myself including HTTP client-server traffic management?

Comment: You don't need. If you can differentiate the requests from different client based on content/any other factor, send them to two different endpoints. Is that you need?

Comment: Yes, ok, I'll try it out in the next days. Thanks!